# Is there a way to speed up web scraping with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, twitter, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am scraping the Twitter website. (API is not used to retrieve historical data.) .Smaller ranges will come up sooner, but if you make a larger range, you'll have to spend a lot of time.

Also, there is an error that the connection is stopped after a long period of time.

So my query is, Is there any way to speed up web scraping with Selenium ? Or do I need to modify my code?

```
#python3
import requests
import time  
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS('C:\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs')
url =u'https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&vertical=default&q=%EC%84%B8%EC%9B%94%ED%98%B8%20since%3A2014-04-16%20until%3A2014-04-17&src=typd&lang=ko'


browser.get(url)
time.sleep(1)

body = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')


for _ in range(10000):
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(0.1)

tweets=browser.find_elements_by_class_name('tweet-text')

wfile = open("140416.txt", mode='w', encoding='utf8')
data={}
i = 1
for i, tweet in enumerate(tweets):
    data['text'] = tweet.text
    print(i, ":", data)
    wfile.write(str(data) +'\n')
    i += 1
wfile.close()
```

Comment: your script is sleeping for 100 ms x 10000 times = 1000 sec = ~17 min in total. So modifying your code like this: `# time.sleep(0.1)` will make your script 17 min faster.

Comment: You could also use the .findAll from BeautifulSoup to grab the tweets (you pass in e.g.  driver.page_source). Bs4 is not the speed of light but still way faster at parsing html than selenium.

Comment: @jlaur 
With BeautifulSoup, will not you only bring twenty tweets? I have to bring several tweets,
Do you know how to import multiple tweets using BeautifulSoup?
If you do not mind, can you teach me?

Comment: You still use selenium for retrieving the data, but parse it with bs4. tweets=BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser").findAll(whatevertagyouneed)

Comment: Btw - have you tried to check if the content loads through an ajax call of some sort? If that's the case you could use that instead...

Comment: Scraping the Twitter website is against the [Terms of Service](https://twitter.com/en/tos), and your IP address may be banned if you do this. You should use the API instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There are a lot of data. According to my script, there are 8509 tweets. So it requires ~425 scroll downs. Each scroll down may take 0.8-5 seconds. Hence, scrolling down will take ~14-20 minutes.

2. Repeat scroll down 10,000 times doesn't guarantee that it will load all tweets. You had better count elements after scrolling down, check if it increases or not.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import time

dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = (
    "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/53 "
    "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.87"
)
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap, executable_path='path')
url =u'https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&vertical=default&q=%EC%84%B8%EC%9B%94%ED%98%B8%20since%3A2014-04-16%20until%3A2014-04-17&src=typd&lang=ko'
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(3)

ended = False
try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".tweet-text"))
    )
except:
    print("Can't find tweet text.")

tweetCount = int(browser.execute_script("return document.querySelectorAll('.tweet-text').length"))
retryCount = 0
startTime = time.time()
sleepTime=1
while not ended:
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(sleepTime)
    timeX= time.time()
    newCount = int(browser.execute_script("return document.querySelectorAll('.tweet-text').length"));
    timeY=time.time()
    if(newCount > tweetCount):
        tweetCount = newCount
        retryCount = 0
        print("Count: " + str(tweetCount))
    else:
        retryCount = retryCount + 1
        if(retryCount>=5):
            ended = True
            retryCount = 0


endScrollDownTime = time.time()
tweets = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.tweet-text')
wfile = open("140416.txt", mode='w', encoding='utf8')
data={}
i = 1
for i, tweet in enumerate(tweets):
    data['text'] = tweet.text
    wfile.write(str(data) +'\n')
    i += 1


endGetTextTime = time.time()
time1 = endScrollDownTime-startTime
time2 = endGetTextTime - endScrollDownTime
overAll = endGetTextTime - startTime
print('\n\nLength: '+str(len(tweets))+ '\nScrolldown Time:' + str(time1) + '\nGetText Time: ' + str(time2) + '\nOverall: ' + str(overAll))
browser.quit()
```

Comment: "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/53 "
    "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.87"  what is mean?

I am using 64 bit for Windows 10. Is it usable as it is? If I have to fix it, how do I fix it?

Comment: @jiji it's 'User-Agent' of web browser. I have to set it. Otherwise, twitter won't work on my machine. You can set other values. See example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent).

Comment: I'm turning now. I also have questions. How do I fix if I want to see the contents of a tweet with count? 1. apple (enter) 2.bus (enter) /// There is no enter function in comments. In other words, you want to store tweets by line.

Comment: @jiji Tweets are stored one by one. If you want to see number of each tweet, just add `i` to `wfile.write(str(data) +'\n')`. E.g. `wfile.write(str(i) + ": " + str(data) +'\n')`.